# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused (c# socket program)

Tags: c#, sockets

I just copied the code from msdn examples, asynchronous server and client socket program. But I am getting error System.Net.SocketsException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:11000

Client Program :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject
{
// Client socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 256;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
// The port number for the remote device.
private const int port = 11000;

// ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);

// The response from the remote device.
private static String response = String.Empty;

private static void StartClient()
{
    // Connect to a remote device.
    try
    {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // The name of the 
        // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        // Send test data to the remote device.
        Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
        sendDone.WaitOne();

        // Receive the response from the remote device.
        Receive(client);
        receiveDone.WaitOne();

        // Write the response to the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

        // Release the socket.
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

        // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
        sendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartClient();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Server Program :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
// Client  socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 1024;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
// Thread signal.
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public AsynchronousSocketListener()
{
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    // The DNS name of the computer
    // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                content.Length, content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}


public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you change `IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];` to `IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;` in *StartListening*

Comment: Thanks. Problem Solved

Answer (score 1):

change

```
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
```

to

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
```

in *StartListening* method....

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of why it wasn't working, not just a "do this to fix it".

Comment: @GilHamilton MS can do it better than me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The explanation is not for me; I understand why your change fixed the OP's problem. But the answer is of little permanent value if there is no education/explanation accompanying it. Also the explanation should be in the answer itself, not a comment. (Although it's my understanding that pointers to off-site resources are discouraged as they have a tendency to disappear.)